Why does summing the losses for each step in an RNN not lead to convergence?
I have been training an RNN model to predict the next number in an arithmetic sequence (a, a+d, a+2d, a+3d, a+4d, ...). Initially, I summed the loss for each step in the sequence as it is a very common practice. However, this approach did not lead to convergence. When I changed the training loop to only consider the loss from the last step, the model converged.
Can someone explain why summing the losses for each step in an RNN prevents convergence?
Here is the initial training loop that did not converge where I summed the loss at each step (batch size is 1):
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0

    for length, sequence, next_number in dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = 0
        h = torch.zeros(BATCH_SIZE)

        for i in range(length):
            x = torch.cat([h, sequence[0, i].unsqueeze(0)])
            y = sequence[0, i + 1] if i != length - 1 else next_number[0]

            output = model(x)
            h, y_hat = output[0].unsqueeze(0), output[1]

            loss += criterion(y_hat, y)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        total_loss += loss.item()

    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}, Loss: {total_loss/len(dataloader)}')

And here is the modified loop that converged, I only took the loss from the last output:
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0

    for length, sequence, next_number in dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        h = torch.zeros(BATCH_SIZE)

        for i in range(length):
            x = torch.cat([h, sequence[0, i].unsqueeze(0)])
            h = model(x)[0].unsqueeze(0)

            if i == length - 1: loss = criterion(model(x)[1], next_number[0])

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        total_loss += loss.item()

    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}, Loss: {total_loss/len(dataloader)}')

Any insights into why this behavior occurs would be greatly appreciated.
